# Hiding span tag with display none and showing with inline

Tags: css, inline, display, styled-components

I have a menu and, when it is open, it has the `inline` display, and, when it is closed, the span has the display `none` to display only the icon: [see here](https://0i402.csb.app/).

Here is my code:

```
<ButtonWrap>
     <StyledButton style={{padding:0}}>
       <IconWrap name='facebook' size='big'/>
       <MenuText status = { open ? 'inline-flex' : 'none' } > facebook </MenuText> 
    </StyledButton>
 </ButtonWrap>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
export const buttonWrap = css` width: 100% ; height: 50px ;  display: block;  `;

export const buttonBase = css`    background: transparent !important ; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; color: white !important; font-weight: bold !important; font-size: 0.875rem; font-family: Roboto; letter-spacing: 0.3px !important; margin-bottom:
1.4rem !important; &:hover{
    color: white !important;
    background-color:rgba(186,186,186,0.4) !important; } &:focus{
    color: white !important;
    background-color:#444bf8 !important; }`;

export const IconWrap = styled(Icon)` display: inline !important; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; height: '1em'; `;
```

All my code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-cache-0i402).

Comment: One design choice you could make is to set the closed CSS to be a fixed width, and set `overflow: hidden;` to hide the extra text instead of setting `display: none;`. Alternatively, you could set `opacity: 0;` on close, and `opacity: 1;` while open.

Comment: could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change up your style.css in your sandbox to the following:

```
.ui.button {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ui.button > span {
  opacity: 0;
}
.lnSeap .ui.button > span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

A combination of the items in my comment allow the transition to happen smoothly. When animating, changing the `display` property drastically changes the layout, in a way that on-off switches change a light status drastically compared to a dimmer switch.

The `opacity` can gradually change from 0 to 1 (in decimal increments) for animations. The `nowrap` and `hidden` properties keep the span tag in place when the sidebar shrinks.

Comment: for me to make a transition fade i would have to put in width and opacity?

Comment: I realized that width is not needed at all, since the shrinking isn't dependant on the span tag. But I added in opacity to phase it out, and the nowrap + overflow to avoid that tag from moving.